# An entire function all whose forward orbits are bounded

Tags: cv.complex-variables, ds.dynamical-systems, complex-dynamics, discrete-dynamical-systems

**Edit:** I revise the question according to the comment of  Gabe  Conant.

What is  an example of  a non constant entire function $f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ which satisfy the following?:

> For  every $z\in \mathbb{C}$, the sequence $z,f(z),f^2(z),\ldots,f^n(z),\ldots$ is  a  bounded sequence  but $f$ is  not in the form $f(z)=\lambda z,\; |\lambda|\leq 1$.

Comment: Do you also want $f$ to be non-constant?

Comment: @GabeConant  Yes. Thank you. i revise the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given an entire function $f\colon\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$, the *escaping set*, $I(f)$, is the set of $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $f^n(z)\to\infty$. Per the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escaping_set#Properties), the escaping set of a non-linear entire function is nonempty.

The reference for this is *[On the iteration of entire functions](http://www.math.purdue.edu/~eremenko/dvi/banach.pdf)* by Eremenko.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @AliTaghavi You're welcome! I assume you also didn't want a linear example like $f(z)=(z+1)/2$.

Comment: Yes I  should exclude the linear case too. but i  did not pay attention (and  i was not aware of ) to this linear case $(z+1)/2$

Comment: Dynamically, it is the same as  $z\mapsto z/2$  with translation of the fixed point.